# How to redirect users after form submission?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, elementor

**Objective:**
To redirect users to different pages after they submit a form in Elementor. The redirection will be based on a javascript variable that is stored. I have given the submit button an ID called `submitbutt`.

**Implementation:**
For the Form in Elementor, I have selected the `Actions after submit` to `Redirect`. Also in the  `Redirect` section, I had selected the `to Shortcode` option and made reference to my shortcode `[elementor-template id="1343"]`.

**The shortcode**

It is a HTML that includes a javascript and it looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('submitbutt').onclick = function() {
if (localStorage.getItem('pagex') === 'page_1') {
 window.location = 'https://www.website.com/error/?1';
}
else if (localStorage.getItem('pagex') === 'page_2') {
  window.location = 'https://www.website.com/error/?2';
}
else {
 window.location = 'https://www.website.com/error/';
}
  };

</script>
```

**Problem:** After users hit the submit button, no redirect occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('submitbutt').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (localStorage.getItem('pagex') === 'page_1') {
 window.location = 'https://www.website.com/error/?1';
}
else if (localStorage.getItem('pagex') === 'page_2') {
  window.location = 'https://www.website.com/error/?2';
}
else {
 window.location = 'https://www.website.com/error/';
}
});
```

Use an event handler with buttons

For forms, to customise the behaviour of the button, use [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)